# How can i SendMessage to other processes windows then notepad?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1

```
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;

        //include FindWindowEx
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        //include SendMessage
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Then in the constructor

```
//getting notepad's process | at least one instance of notepad must be running
            Process notepadProccess = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv")[0];

            //getting notepad's textbox handle from the main window's handle
            //the textbox is called 'Edit'
            IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
            //sending the message to the textbox
            SendMessage(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Testing");
```

This is working for the notepad.
But if i want to send a message to another visual studio opened window of a project ?

For example i created a new project in a new visual studio and created in the project a new class called it test
And i want to send to the class some text for example:

```
using system;
```

For example this is the new class window:

[image: test]

After sending the message it will be like this:

[image: test]

Comment: Use standard input and/or standard output.  You can open notepad from Process Class and use standard input/output to send and receive inputs from notepad.

Comment: what parameters do you use in `FindWindowEx` for visual studio?

Comment: @LeiYang None. The only change i did when tried to send for the visual studio window was: Process notepadProccess = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv")[0]; changed notepad with devenv this find the visual studio but it didn't send to it anything. When it was "notepad" it was working fine sent the message to the notepad but when changed it to "devnev" it's not sending to the visual studio. Nothing else i tried/changed so far.

Comment: Most processes will not have this window: `IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null)`

Comment: It sounds like this should be a Visual Studio Extension project.  You will have access to the entire VS API for manipulating the GUI and loaded documents using it, instead of having the rely on p/invoke.